# How to proof $I(X;Y) \le \min (H(X),H(Y))$?

Tags: probability, statistics

We know mutual information formula:
$I(X;Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)$

But how to proof $I(X;Y) \le \min (H(X),H(Y))$?
Or can you give the proof or web address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By the equations you've written,
\begin{align*}
H(X) \geq H(X) - H(X \mid Y) &= I(X;Y) \\
H(Y) \geq H(Y) - H(Y \mid X) &= I(X;Y) \\
\end{align*}
since $H(X \mid Y)$ and $H(Y \mid X)$ are non-negative. Thus $I(X;Y) \leq H(X)$ and $I(X;Y) \leq H(Y) \Rightarrow I(X;Y) \leq \min(H(X),H(Y))$.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Xiang,

Yes,from your tip,$H(X|Y) \ge 0,H(Y|X) \ge 0$,

so we can assume
$\min (H(X),H(Y)) = H(X)$,

we can get $H(X|Y) = 0$,then $H(Y|X) \ge 0$

we can say

${\rm{H(X|Y)}} =  - \sum\limits_{x,y} {p(x,y)\log p(x|y)}  =  - \sum\limits_{x,y} {p(x,y)\log \frac{{p(x,y)}}{{p(y)}} = 0 \Rightarrow p(x,y) = p(y)} \\
{\rm{H(Y|X)}} =  - \sum\limits_{x,y} {p(x,y)\log p(y|x)}  =  - \sum\limits_{x,y} {p(x,y)\log \frac{{p(x,y)}}{{p(x)}}}  =  - \sum\limits_{x,y} {p(y)\log \frac{{p(y)}}{{p(x)}}}  \ge 0 \\ \Rightarrow p(x) \ge p(y)
$

How can we say,when $p(x,y) = p(y)$,then always $p(x) \ge p(y)$?